# Busy Cursor location on screen

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm using a `BusyCursor` feature in `wxpython` as follows:

```
wx.BeginBusyCursor()
a = wx.BusyInfo("Action in Proggress")

very long action

wx.EndBusyCursor()
a.Destroy()
```

The MSG pops in the center of screen.
How can I control where the MSG appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The `wx.BusyInfo` widget does not support setting its window position. If you need that, I would recommend using a subclass of `wx.Dialog` or `wx.MessageDialog`.